# What does the On-boarding mean?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-indy

I am reading the getting started from indy-node. The getting-started.svg shows flows with Onboarding steps, i.e. *Apply for the job with Acme - Onboarding*. What does this mean? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[You can read about it on Medium](https://kctheservant.medium.com/exploring-hyperledger-indy-through-indy-dev-example-10075d2547ae).

The meanings are:

- ***Onboarding***

  - `the process of integrating a new employee with a company and its culture`
- ***Acme***

  - `Acme corp.`